# Obtengo el error I/Choreographer: Skipped 110 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, linux, ubuntu

Estoy trabajando en android studio intentando hacer una conexion con una maquina virtual en ubuntu desktop ya hace la conexion pero cuando le paso algunos comandos (no todos) lanza este error

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
```

A lo que tengo entendido es que el thread principal no soporta el proceso y se lo salta, este es el codigo que ejecuta el proceso

```
Button enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_consola);
        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    String result = executeRemoteCommand(email, password, comando.getText().toString(), host);
                    System.out.println(result);
                    tv.setText(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Tambien intente usar `runOnUiThread` pero no se muy bien como funciona y cuando lo uso me dice que no puede acceder a la variable `tv` que es un `TextView` que muestra el texto que sale en la consola de la maquina virtual

Comment: Tu aplicación esta haciendo mucho trabajo en el mainThread, lo que hace que se pase del tiempo que tiene para dibujar cada frame (16 milisegundos), que en realidad es menos, porque el mismo thread ocupa alguno de esos 16ms para calcular tamaños y demás del frame a pintar. Lo que deberías hacer es controlar que el método "executeRemoteCommand" no este bloqueando el mainThread hasta que complete su tarea. Deberías ejecutar ese método en un backgroundThread y devolver el resultado al mainThread, así no lo bloqueas.

Comment: @AugustoHerbel eso seria crear un metodo aparte que haga el thread?

Comment: @AugustoHerbel ademas cuando lo hago en un thread aparte, se queda sin hacer nada como si estuviera cargando pero no hace nada

Comment: agrega el codigo que utilizas para hacer ese trabajo asi te puedo ayudar. Además estaría bueno que pongas lo que hace "executeRemoteCommand" para saber si es un trabajo pesado o algo relativamente liviano de realizar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no se genera al dar "clic" en el botón, en realidad se debe a otro proceso diferente. La descripción:

> "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.”

**indica que el código está tardando mucho en procesarse y algunos frames se están omitiendo debido a esto, esto debido a un procesamiento pesado que se esta realizando en la aplicación**, al accesar a la base de datos o alguna tarea que provoque que el thread se detenga por un momento.

Entre varias causas puedo comentarte que este problema se genera comunmente:

> • Al anidar varios Layouts principalmente RelativeLayouts , por lo que
>   debes optimizar tus layouts.
>
> • Al cargar varias imagenes de tamaño considerable en las vistas
>   continuamente.
>
> • Usar una única imagen para varias densidades y tamaños de pantalla,
>   considera usar las apropiadas para cada directorio /drawable- o
>   /mipmap-
>
> • Acceso o escritura a base de datos se genera en el thread principal.

Esto puede no considerarse un error que provoque tu aplicación no funcione, pero indica que tienes que optimizarla.

Revisar:

**[The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126690/250260)**
 (inglés)